# how to force user to change password after first login

Tags: password, ansible

I am trying to setup a rule that every newly created user must change his password after first login.

I know it can be done manually , i.e to force users to change password at next login.

```
chage -d 0 username
or 
passwd --expire username
```

The idea to make this change as permanent and each user that will be created must change it password at his first login.

I have to use this logic with my ansible playbook.

Comment: There's [an `expires` attribute for `user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-expires)

Comment: expire attribute works only if I have to create the users. I want to setup a rule when ever user is created with " useradd username" , and password is set, it should ask to change password at first login.

I could not find any files that may contain this information @muru

Comment: I don't think that's the case. `expires` should update the attribute of existing users too. Why are you using `useradd` in Ansible, anyway?

Comment: I am NOT creating users via ansible. Users will be created manually. Just want to save this logic as permanent for existing and new users on multiple servers. I hope question is clear
@muru

Comment: For `useradd` you could set `EXPIRE` in `/etc/default/useradd`

Comment: I have set EXPIRE=0  in /etc/default/useradd , but it has no Affect  @muru.
any more suggestions that I can try out.

Comment: Don't you think EXPIRE=1 if it has to work?

Comment: @ArturMeinild EXPIRE=1 also does not work.